# Detect Mac device color (Swift)

Tags: swift, macos, core-graphics, iokit

I am wondering if it is possible to detect the color of the Mac my app is running on?

```
extension NSScreen {

    var cgDirectDisplayId: CGDirectDisplayID? {
        let description = self.deviceDescription
        return description[NSDeviceDescriptionKey("NSScreenNumber")] as? CGDirectDisplayID
    }

    var modelNumber: String? {
        guard let displayId = self.cgDirectDisplayId else {
            return nil
        }
        return String(format: "%02X", CGDisplayModelNumber(displayId)).lowercased()
    }

}
```

... this gives me the `modelNumber` of `NSScreen` and enables me to differentiate if it’s an iMac or MacBook for example. However, it lacks information about the devices color and also doesn’t help with devices like the Mac mini which can have multiple colors (silver/grey) but comes without an built-in display.

Any hint would be much appreciated!

Comment: This was figured out be Steve Troughton-Smith, https://twitter.com/stroughtonsmith/status/1478039753274675203?s=21 https://gist.github.com/steventroughtonsmith/f1f4b486555945d1a1e4994180eb8a91 and  thanks to Brett Best for digging it out https://twitter.com/brettbestaus
If this works for you please turn it into a more SO style answer.

Comment: @RhythmicFistman Really appreciate your reply! However, I am searching for a way to detect the color of the hardware itself. Your links seem to refer to determine the accentColor of macOS.

Comment: Doesn't the accent colour reflect that?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The `accentColor` is the highlight color used by the macOS UI. It is easily changeable within system settings.

Comment: ah that's too bad